# Add class to label

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Why this dont work? When I change `"$(this).toggleClass('checked');"` on `alert('test')` and click label, I see alert window :-/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("label").click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('checked');
    });
});

<input type="radio" name="hours" id="hours1" value="xyz" style="display: none" />
<label for="hours1">10:00</label>
<input type="radio" name="hours" id="hours2" value="xyz" style="display: none" />
<label for="hours2">11:00</label>
```

Comment: why do you think it doesn't work? What's your css?

Comment: What happens instead? Not working is a bad description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this [working code](http://jsfiddle.net/4pQt8/) . I hope, it fulfills your need

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("label").click(function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('checked')){
            $(this).addClass('checked');
        }else{
               $(this).toggleClass('checked');
        }
    });
});

<input type="radio" name="hours" id="hours1" value="xyz" style="display: block" />
<label for="hours1">10:00</label>
<input type="radio" name="hours" id="hours2" value="xyz" style="display: block" />
<label for="hours2">11:00</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming what you want to do is to have the currently selected checkbox's label have the "checked" class:

http://jsfiddle.net/4pQt8/3/

Note: You'll need to refine the `$("label")` selector, because as it is now, it'll remove the checked class from all labels in the document.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name=\"hours\"]").change(function(){
        if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
            $("label").removeClass("checked");
            $("label[for=\"" + $(this).attr("id") + "\"]").addClass("checked");
        }
    });
});
```

​